# Google APP Engine and cloud sql :: Unable to connect Spring boot app in Google cloud sql (my sql)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am getting this error while connecting my Spring boot APP inside APP engine in Google cloud sql.
[image]

Below I have attached code from application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/myprojectID?cloudSqlInstance=myInstance:us-central1:my-sql-instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=myPassword
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In cloud sql default configuration I have used to create database.
Whenever I fire this command I am getting this error.

> mvn -DskipTests package appengine:deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the @zenny's comment that served as a solution, In order to solve the issue, you've to set private IP in your [SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip) and use that private IP for your database local url.

[Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/connecting-to-cloud-sql/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) is a Codelabs tutorial which you can follow to set private IP for your SQL instance.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this tutorial for Spring Application.
[Spring Pet Clinic using Cloud SQL](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-petclinic-cloudsql/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4)

One difference that I noticed was in pom.xml:

````
     ```<!-- Add CloudSQL Starter for MySQL -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
  </dependency>
````

Also in [Spring Cloud GCP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gcp):

```
     SQL - MySQL

     Cloud SQL integrations with MySQL

     org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql
```

You can find more information [Spring Cloud GCP MySQL Sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-mysql-sample)

## EDIT:

I was able to Deploy Spring Boot Application (Pet Clinic) on App Engine standard. Here you can find my [pom.xml](https://github.com/mvladoi/spring_boot_app_engine/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: Have you used standard APP Engine or local tomcat? I had also use the linked example you given but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am using Tomcat and is working , I had to add `spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=` in the `application.properties` file

Comment: Hey @Zenny, did this solution work out for you? If so, do not forget to mark this answer as accepted and upvote it for greater visibility to other community users. Otherwise, please point out what issue you are currently facing, and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: @sllopis No , this solution not worked for me. I have settled private IP inside my GCP sql instance and use that IP in my database local url. And that is working now.

Comment: Hi @Zenny, can you please write your solution out as an answer? it can be helpful for other users running into the same or similar issues to see how you solved it.